# pythonicly looping for two variables

Tags: python

I have two variables

```
odds=[1,3,5]
evens=[2,4,6]
```

and i want to print them in a loop like this:

```
for i in range(0,2):
  print(odds[i])
  print(evens[i])
```

to get an output like

1,2,3,4,5,6.

However the above loop doesn't feel very pythonic. Is there way of doing this more pythonicly? perhaps with a loop thats defined via a line like "for odd in odd and for even in even:"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for x,y in zip(odds,evens):
    print(x,",",y)
```